# Can the subject of a sentence also be its object?

Tags: subjects, relative-pronouns, objects

Can the subject of a sentence also be its object?

In the sentence, "There came a man who was sent from God," is "man" both the subject of "came" and the object of "sent"?

Comment: It's possible and common for a noun to be object of a main clause and subject of a subordinate clause (*the man* in *I thanked the man who saved my life*) or vice versa, but that isn't what's happening here. Any basic grammar will explain who/whom/which/that.

Comment: @StuartF I wouldn't go along with what you say. In your example, the subject of "saved" in the relative clause is realised by "who". "Who" does of course _refer_ to "man" (the antecedent), but it's "who", not "man" that is the grammatical subject.

Answer (score 1):

*There came a man who was sent from God*.

No: what you suggest would be a theoretical impossibility. The subject of "came" is the dummy pronoun "there". "Sent" has no object; rather, it has as its complement the PP "from God".

Note also that it's a presentational construction, where the NP "a man who was sent from God" is not object of "came" but a displaced subject.

Such constructions are called 'presentationals'. They differ from ordinary existentials by virtue of having some verb other then "be" as predicator.

Comment: Grammatically BillJ is right. However, there's a gotcha in that they can be physically the same. e.g.

"I hit Paul" - different subject and object.

"I hit myself" - different subject and object in terms of the words "I" and "myself" but actually the same physical being.